# How to backup a mongodb database with authorization enabled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, digital-ocean

I am running a mongo database on Digital Ocean. I've set it up with the following tutorial: [Mongodb setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-remote-access-for-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04) and secured it with this tutorial: [MongoDb security](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Now I am trying to create a dump of a particular database. I am using the following command as stated in this article: [Backup & Restore Mongodb](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-restore-and-migrate-a-mongodb-database-on-ubuntu-18-04):

`sudo mongodump --db dbName --out /var/backups/mongobackups/`date +"%m-%d-%y"``

However, I am getting the following error message:

```
Failed: error getting collections for database 'dbName': error running 'listCollections'. Database: 'dbName' Err: command listCollections requires authentication.
```

I've logged in on my server with root user. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe better follow these ones: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error clearly says "command listCollections requires authentication." you should try "Dump database with username & password mongodump -u=USERNAME -p=PASSWORD --db=DB_NAME."

:)

Comment: I want aware I could use the -u and -p like that :). This is what ended up working for me:
`sudo mongodump --username Username --password Password --authenticationDatabase admin --db dbName --out /var/backups/mongobackups/`date +"%m-%d-%y"``